# vo_ros/vo: malloc(): memory corruption caused by image size?

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I want to set up the monocular visual odometry system by the *Robotics and Perception Group* of the university of Zurich for a robotics project. Project site is https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo. They implemented it as ROS node what is really cool, but when I launch the svo_ros node `roslaunch svo_ros live.launch` I get an error:

```
[ INFO] [1455715165.624976791]: SVO initialized
[ INFO] [1455715165.625768093]: Found parameter: svo/cam_topic, value: /image_raw
[ INFO] [1455715197.445786640]: RESET
*** Error in `/home/user/workspace/indigo/devel/lib/svo_ros/vo': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000001187920 ***
```

I would guess this is caused by a wrong image size configuration, so the OpenCV functions used by svo corrupt the memory working on the images.
I calibrated my camera using the camera_calibration ros node. I translated the output to the .yaml-file representation in the /param/camera_pinhole.yaml as follows

```
cam_model: Pinhole
cam_width: 644
cam_height: 484
cam_fx: 588.481298
cam_fy: 587.819899
cam_cx: 328.046456
cam_cy: 226.471844
cam_d0: -0.363501
cam_d1: 0.165011
cam_d2: 0.000571
cam_d3: -0.000577
```

As I got the image resolution 644x484 from the calibration data and confirmed it using the image_view node of the image_view package, I would say the image cam_width and height I configured is correct. I even tried to set image_width and image_height in launch-filge to the same size, but it didn't change anything.

```
<launch>

<node pkg="svo_ros" type="vo" name="svo" clear_params="true" output="screen">

        <!-- param name="image_width" value="644" type="int" />
        <param name="image_height" value="484" type="int" />
        <param name="cam_width" value="644" type="int" />
        <param name="cam_height" value="484" type="int" / -->

        <!-- Camera topic to subscribe to -->
        <param name="cam_topic" value="/image_raw" type="str" />

        <!-- Camera calibration file -->
        <rosparam file="$(find svo_ros)/param/camera_pinhole.yaml" />

        <!-- Default parameter settings: choose between vo_fast and vo_accurate -->
        <rosparam file="$(find svo_ros)/param/vo_fast.yaml" />

    </node>

</launch>
```

Did I miss to fit any parameters or other configurations or does someone have an other ideas what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a solution to this issue.

It was caused when making the image pyramid when the image had an odd number of columns.

I fixed it by modifying the file *rpg_vikit/vikit_common/src/vision.cpp*

Line 91 previously read:

```
  const int stride  =  in.step.p[0];
```

I changed it to:

```
  const int stride = in.step.p[0]/2 * 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer @amado. Please take a moment to format your answer to make it more readable: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I have no idea why, but it works. I hope this is pushed soon. Now I have to find out why there are not enough features found after the initialization of the second keyframe. Thank you.